# INSERT INTO with SELECT - number does not match

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have this `INSERT`-statement with a `mat`-table. The `mat`-tables have the same design (same columns etc. but different entries).

```
insert into [tmp].[dbo].[mat]
select *
from [mat7].[dbo].[mat] mat7
join [mat6].[dbo].[mat] mat6 on mat7.myid = mat6.myid and mat7.matnumber <> mat6.matnumber
```

But it doesn't work because the `SELECT`-statement has double count of columns. So maybe I could specify in the `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO` the specific columns but there are 75 - so is there are more easy and shorter way to `SELECT` only the 75 columns?

`SELECT [mat7].*` doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `select mat7.*` should work. What is the error you get?

Comment: are you sure you want to join those tables or you mean `union`? Please try doing select statement first and check if schema match to `mat` table

Comment: red underlined. the column prefix 'mat7' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: can you try insert into [tmp].[dbo].[mat]
select mat7.*
from [mat7].[dbo].[mat] mat7
join [mat6].[dbo].[mat] mat6 on mat7.myid = mat6.myid and mat7.matnumber <> mat6.matnumber. Instead of [mat7].* try mat7.*

Comment: I've tried `select mat7.*` again now it works... . Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specifiy [mat7].[Col1],[Mat7].[Col2] etc..

You could extract the columnnames from syscolumns 
ie  (untested)

```
Declare @cols varchar(max)
Select @Cols = @cols +',[Mat7].'+Name from syscolumns where    
object_id=object_id('mat')
select @cols
```

Would get you started ..  It is always best to avoid *s and to specify the columns on the table you are inserting to.